# Why is image not displaying on HTML document?

Tags: html, image, src

I have some images and I am using the following code to show them. But they are not visible till now.

#### Code:

```
<div class="sto-title"><a href='http://www.sharetheorb.com'> 
    <img src="img/orb-header-logo2.png" alt="SharetheOrb"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: We need more code. With this information given, it could be everything, like in CSS: img { display: none; } Did you check with the browser-inspector if the image gets rendered into the document? If the image tag is there?

Comment: Use inspect element in your browser to determine if the image is in the correct location and if there is any css rules being applied to it that may cause this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to make it better as far as I could understand. Please, add more information and more specific so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the image and the file in the same folder? If you do then maybe you should convert your png file to jpg. This is a problem that I have frequently seen even in my code so I think that you might have the same problem. You can convert png to jpg [here](http://png2jpg.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your markup, and the image URL is returning a 404, so I'm assuming there is typo somewhere, a missing file, or a directory permission setting somewhere.

http://www.sharetheorb.com/img/orb-header-logo2.png

http://www.sharetheorb.com/img/ - gives a 403 so guessing with the permissions are wrong, or more likely directory browsing is disabled (which is a good practice anyway)

A couple of questions

- what does the directory structure look like in your webroot?
- what are the file permissions on /img/ and the image it's self?

  - `ls -la` can tell you this in each case.

Comment: To be honest, I'm a bit of an amateur when it comes to the above. structure is sharetheorb.com/img/orb-header-logo2.png

Comment: Do you have access to the shell? so that you can copy n paste the output of `ls -a`? It sounds like you have the correct path, but not permissions